# MonthCalendar controls changes size on different systems, how to adapt form to accomodate?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog, monthcalendar

I made a simple date picker dialog using C# WinForms and the MonthCalendar control. Images below shows the same dialog in Windows 7 and 10. As can be seen, the MonthCalendar is much large, overlapping the buttons.

[image: Windows 7]

[image: Windows 10]

This is unexpected since WinForm controls typically have fixed sizes. I need a way to resize the window and move the buttons relative to the MonthCalendar.

Question: How to best handle situations like this, preferably automatically?

Answer (score 1):

A `TableLayoutPanel`. Two columns, three rows. Dock it on the form. Place the Calendar in the left column, spanning all 3 rows. Put the buttons in the right column in rows 1 and 2. Set Column 1 size mode to Auto-size. You may also need to make Column 2 auto-size and then set the tablelayoutpanel to autosize and then finally the form to auto-size (make sure you allow it to grow and shrink).

Comment: This seems like a proper solution, but I was never able to get it working. TableLayoutPanel is not easy to work with. For my simple form I ended up moving the controls by hand.

Comment: This is my solution that moves the buttons and expands the form: `buttonOk.Left = monthCalendar.Left + monthCalendar.Width; buttonCancel.Left = monthCalendar.Left + monthCalendar.Width; this.Width = buttonCancel.Left + buttonCancel.Width + monthCalendar.Left;`